# Printing lines of file without including newline in Python 2.7

Tags: file, python-2.7, printing, io

I am trying to print the contents of a file. I have a file `maze.txt` with the following contents:

```
7 7
1 1 R N E
1 2 B N W
1 3 B N N
```

And I am printing it using the following code:

```
with open(os.path.join('maze.txt')) as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
    f.close()
```

However, my output has extra empty lines in between:

```
7 7

1 1 R N E

1 2 B N W

1 3 B N N
```

I've tried changing my print line to `print line[0:-1]`, which works except it will cut off the last character in the final line because there's not a newline to get rid of after it. Is there an easy way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a comma at the end of the print statement:

`print line,`

Answer (score 1):

Just as the previous answer: when the print function doesn't end with a ',', then it adds a 'newline'.

Also, on your code, when opening a file with the 'with' code, you don't need to close the file: it's closed automatically when exiting the 'with' chunk of code.